# Slowing down row insertion animation in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, animation

Is there a way to slow down the row insertion/deletion animation ?

In my particular case, I'm expanding/colapsing a cell by adding/removing rows below my cell and I'd like to slow the animation a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the below tricks to animate insert/delete the table view cells in my project, which works fine.

you can try this out. Happy coding!!!

```
// Here you can change the animation duration based on ur needs
NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 2.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{

        // Disable the user interaction to the view if needed, otherwise user may interact with table view.
        //view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [tableview beginUpdates];


        // insert object to table view data source
        //[yourArray insertObject:@"Some object" atIndex:some indexpath];

        // Perform insert animation
        //[tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:someindexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

        [tableview endUpdates];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSLog(@"Animation done");

        // Enable the user interaaction now
        //view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add/remove rows as following :

```
[_tableView beginUpdates];

// your add/remove func

[_tableView endUpdates];
```

Do UI changes for Tableview like above to reduce slow behaviour.

Hope it helps..